# replaceWith() not working on cloned, detached nodes

Tags: jquery, clone

`replaceWith()` is not working properly for me.  For example, given this HTML:

```html
<div id="tree1">
    <div>
        <h3>Item 1</h3>
        <h3>Item 2</h3>
        <h3>Item 3</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

this code does not replace the `<h3>` nodes with `<li>`s:

```js
var items_Bad   = $("#tree1 div h3").clone ();

$("#tree1 div").remove ();
$("#tree1").append ('<ul id="Items1"></ul>');

//--- This does not replace anything!
items_Bad.replaceWith (function () {
    return ('<li>' + $(this).text () + '</li>');
} );

$("#Items1").append (items_Bad);
```

But this code does! :

```js
var items_Good  = $("#tree1 div h3").clone ();

$("#tree1 div").remove ();
$("#tree1").append ('<ul id="Items1"></ul>');

$("#Items1").append (items_Good);

//--- But, this works!
$("#Items1 h3"). replaceWith (function () {
    return ('<li>' + $(this).text () + '</li>');
} );
```

[**See the jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/tJrLh/)

Here, `replaceWith()` works only if the nodes are (re)attached to the DOM, but [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) says that:

> As of jQuery 1.4, .replaceWith() can also work on disconnected DOM
>   nodes.

What am I missing?

(Note that I don't control the original page's source. And, I have a lot more manipulation to do, so reattaching the nodes prematurely to manipulate them is undesirable.)

Comment: replaceWith() used to work fine when my code was based on jQuery 1.4.4. When I switched to jQuery 1.9.1 (without making any other changes in the code), .replaceWith stopped working. I guess I will stay with jQuery 1.4.4. Whoever is involved in jQuery project doesn't seem to understand the meaning of backward compatibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below is the part of `replaceWith()` that deals with replacing detached nodes (taken straight from the [jQuery 1.7.1 source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js), modulo minor formatting differences):

```
replaceWith: function(value) {
    if (this[0] && this[0].parentNode) {
        // This deals with attached nodes...
    } else {
        return this.length
            ? this.pushStack(jQuery(jQuery.isFunction(value) ? value() : value),
                "replaceWith", value)
            : this;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are two limitations that prevent this code from fulfilling your requirements:

- The supplied function is only called once instead of once per element in the set,
- The supplied function is called in the global context (i.e. the element being replaced is not available through the `this` keyword).

So, I'm afraid replacing detached nodes is still a work in progress, and you will have to fall back to your second solution until the limitations above are fixed.

Comment: Thanks.  Should I file a bug report or feature request? (I'm wavering since I never needed this before and already have a work-around.)

Comment: A [brief search](http://bugs.jquery.com/search?q=replaceWith&go=&ticket=on) does not seem to return anything related, so you might want to open a ticket, yes. Whether you go for `[bug]` or `[feature-request]` is up to you (I'm also personally quite undecided about this, so I wouldn't move before coming up with a submittable patch).

Comment: I have this same problem, has anyone managed to come up with a more elegant solution than attaching to global? I'm trying to make a TinyMCE plugin, so the HTML I'm working with is editorial content, not related to the CMS page itself.